# Real-time Updates for Facebook Events

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

I realize this isn't possible yet, but I was curious if anyone knew if this is even on the horizon for Facebook.  I'd like to be able to subscribe to an event and receive updates when people RSVP to update my server with that information.  Polling is my only current alternative and it's very cumbersome/unreliable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook Graph api real time updates for events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431807/facebook-graph-api-real-time-updates-for-events)

Answer (score 0):

After the major update in July, subscribing to the events connection is now possible:

"Here are the list of User connections to which you can subscribe: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins, location, **events**."

Today, It will only send you a notification when the logged in user has accepted an invitation. Hopefully, they will at at least change this so that you get notified when the logged in user receives an invitation.

I hope this helps! Best of luck!

Comment: This is halfway there... I really want to be able to subscribe to the event itself, not just the user's connection to the event.  This is great for users that I know about, but if they've never logged into my system, I have no way of receiving the notification.  Also I don't want to be blasted with every event the the user accepts, just the one I care about.