# facebook Graph api real time updates for events

Tags: facebook

i want to subscribe for events update using graph api currently i am Subscribing using folowing url

**`https://graph.facebook.com/{App_id}/subscriptions?access_token=XXX&object=user&fields=events&verify_token=YYY&callback_url=http://localhost:8080/`**

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Facebook Graph API [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/), the API currently supports...

> ...the following list of User connections to which you can subscribe: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins.
>
> You can't subscribe to these User connections yet: home, tagged, posts, photos, albums, videos, groups, notes, events, inbox, outbox, updates, accounts.

It's possible that events support will be implemented later.

Comment: moreover, you can't use http://localhost:8080/ as a callback URL - as "localhost" to facebook is facebook - not you.  You have to give Facebook a publicly accessible endpoint.

Comment: yeah i knew that i was looking for an indirect way.if some how it is possible but strugled for two weeks and found no alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to events now works after the recent major update.(July)

Here are the list of User connections to which you can subscribe: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins, location, **events**.